# PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column sections.row_order does not exist

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

```
<% @course.sections.rank(:row_order).each do |section| %>
    <br /><br />
        <div class="section">
            <h3>
                <%= section.title %>
            </h3>
```

I am getting undefined column for that row order in section. Here is my model for section...

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :course
has_many :lessons

include RankedModel
ranks :row_order, :with_same => :course_id
end
```

Here is my migration.

```
class AlterSectionsAddRowOrder < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :sections, :row_order, :integer
    add_index :sections, :row_order
  end
end
```

If this is of any use, here is the error message I get.

Started GET "/courses/13" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-05-07 23:41:49 +0000
Processing by CoursesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"13"}
  Course Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" WHERE "courses"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "13"]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Course Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "courses" INNER JOIN "enrollments" ON "courses"."id" = "enrollments"."course_id" WHERE "enrollments"."user_id" = $1 AND "courses"."id" = 13 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 2]]
  Section Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "sections".* FROM "sections" WHERE "sections"."course_id" = $1 ORDER BY "sections"."row_order" ASC  [["course_id", 13]]
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column sections.row_order does not exist
LINE 1: ...ons"  WHERE "sections"."course_id" = $1  ORDER BY "sections"...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "sections".* FROM "sections"  WHERE "sections"."course_id" = $1  ORDER BY "sections"."row_order" ASC
  Rendered courses/show.html.erb within layouts/application (57.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 240ms

ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column sections.row_order does not exist
LINE 1: ...ons"  WHERE "sections"."course_id" = $1  ORDER BY "sections"...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "sections".* FROM "sections"  WHERE "sections"."course_id" = $1  ORDER BY "sections"."row_order" ASC):
    42:     
    43: 
    44:     
    45:         <% @course.sections.rank(:row_order).each do |section| %>
    46:         
    47:             
    48:                 
  app/views/courses/show.html.erb:45:in `_app_views_courses_show_html_erb___522001594__582727588'

Rendered /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (19.6ms)

Started GET "/courses/13" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-05-07 23:41:51 +0000
Processing by CoursesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"13"}
  Course Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" WHERE "courses"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "13"]]
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Course Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "courses" INNER JOIN "enrollments" ON "courses"."id" = "enrollments"."course_id" WHERE "enrollments"."user_id" = $1 AND "courses"."id" = 13 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 2]]
  Section Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "sections".* FROM "sections" WHERE "sections"."course_id" = $1 ORDER BY "sections"."row_order" ASC  [["course_id", 13]]
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column sections.row_order does not exist
LINE 1: ...ons"  WHERE "sections"."course_id" = $1  ORDER BY "sections"...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "sections".* FROM "sections"  WHERE "sections"."course_id" = $1  ORDER BY "sections"."row_order" ASC
  Rendered courses/show.html.erb within layouts/application (51.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 163ms

ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column sections.row_order does not exist
LINE 1: ...ons"  WHERE "sections"."course_id" = $1  ORDER BY "sections"...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "sections".* FROM "sections"  WHERE "sections"."course_id" = $1  ORDER BY "sections"."row_order" ASC):
    42:     
    43: 
    44:     
    45:         <% @course.sections.rank(:row_order).each do |section| %>
    46:         
    47:             
    48:                 
  app/views/courses/show.html.erb:45:in `_app_views_courses_show_html_erb___522001594__582727588'

Rendered /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (21.3ms)

Comment: Did you forget to run migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My immediate guess is you forgot to run migrations and the column never got added.  You can confirm that the column exists (and the migration was run) by looking at your db/schema.rb file.

Comment: Hey Tim. Thanks for the answer. Yeah, the migration was done. After too much time, I decided to go with rake db:drop and now it's working, but the data is all gone.

Answer (score 2):

I tried restarting the server, adding new migration, and checking every code. After getting frustrated, this is what I did..

rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate

All data is gone. But the website is now running normally again.

Comment: Odd - glad you got it fixed!  Somehow it was mixed up.